# Mysqli/PHP prevent certain dirty reads

Tags: php, mysqli

currently I am running into a problem and I am breaking my head over it (although I might be over thinking it).

Currently i have a table in my SQL DB with some products and the amount in stock. People can visit the product page, or order it (or update it if you are an admin). But now I am affraid of race conditions.

The order process happens as following:

**1)** The session starts an Transaction.

**2)** It gets the current amount of units available.

**3)** It checks that the amount to order is available, and it substract the amount.

**4)** It updates the product table with the new "total amount" value. Here is the code very short(without using prepared statements etc. etc.).

```
BEGIN;
SELECT amount FROM products WHERE id=100;
$available=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0];
if($order<=$available){
    $available-=$order;
    UDPATE products SET amount=$available WHERE id=100;
}
//error checking and then ROLLBACK or COMMIT
```

My question now is:
What do i do to prevent dirty readings in step 2, and so the write back of wrong values in step 4?

example: If 1 person orders 10 things of product A, and while it is at step 3, the second person also orders 5 things of product A. So in step 2 it will still get the "old" value and work with that, and thus restores an incorrect number in step 4.

I know i can use "SELECT.... FOR UPDATE" which will put an exclusive lock on the row, but this also prevents an normal user who is just checking the availability(on the product page) to prevent instantaneously loading, while I rather have them to load the page quick than an on the second accurate inventory. So basically i want the read-lock only to apply to clients who will update the value in the same transaction.

Is what I want possible, or do I need to work with what i got? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can address the problem:

1. You can use a function in MySQL, that shall update the stocks and give an error"Sorry, you product just went out of stock!", whenever the balance after deduction goes below 0.

OR (preferred way)

2. You can use [locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) in MySQL. In this case, it shall be a write lock.The write lock shall disable other read requests(BY second person), till the lock is released(BY First Person).

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you, And that is exactly what "SELECT....FOR UPDATE" does, but i only want it to have a exclusive lock for people who are planning to work with that value and update it(not for people who only request it).